# While generating angular project,giving error forms.d.ts

Tags: angular, angular8

Whenever I am creating new angular project,It giving error in forms.d.ts(forms folder) which is present in node_modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete node_modules and package.lock.json and npm install again

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why the error is coming and why we have to delete node modules and package-lock.json file. It could helpful for me..